# The operator $U$ is unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

If $A$ is a selft-adjoint operator, then the operator $U$ defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
U=(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Is unitary.

I know if $U$ is unitary then $U^{*}U=UU^{*}=I$ But when i tried to compute:
\begin{eqnarray*}
U^{*}U&=&{((A+iI)^{-1})}^{*}(A-iI)^{*}(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}\\\
&=&{((A+iI)^{-1})}^{*}(A^{*}-iI^{*})(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
or I tried to compute $UU^{*}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
UU^{*}&=&{(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}((A+iI)^{-1})}^{*}(A-iI)^{*}\\\
&=&{(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}((A+iI)^{-1})}^{*}(A^{*}-iI^{*})
\end{eqnarray*}
I don't know how can I continue with the hypothesis that $A$ is selft-adjoin operator and the way that I have to treat the adjoint inverse. Can you give some hint to continue? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Use the fact that $(S^*)^{-1} = (S^{-1})^*$ and $(iI)^* = -i I$.

Comment: But $(S^{*})^{-1}=(S^{-1})^{*}$ when $S$ is a selft-adjoint operator and bounded right?

Comment: Since $S S^{-1} = I$, $(S S^{-1})^* = (S^{-1})^*S^* = I^* = I$.